# Star Trek (TNG?) episode about finding a planet where the inhabitants want the stories from the ship's library?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I'm looking for the *Star Trek* episode where they encounter a planet where the people want to get the *Enterprise*'s collection of stories from its library.  I think it's about wanting too much stories?

I think it's in TNG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're actually looking for a *Voyager* episode ["Prime Factors"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Factors_(episode)).  In that episode, the Voyager crew meet an advanced race on planet Sikaris with a space-folding technology called a ["spatial trajector"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spatial_trajector), capable of sending them a vast distance toward home.

During negotiations for this technology, the Voyager crew proposes offering their cultural library to the Sikarans. From Memory Alpha:

> Kim then offers the insight of how the Sikarian culture values stories as a measuring device of character and moral value, and proposes the idea of offering the entire ship's library as a bartering token. Janeway approves the idea and plans to run the idea by Gath.

From the [script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/109.htm):

> KIM: Stories. Stories are an important part of their culture. They seem to provide more than entertainment. They're kind of a measuring rod of values and beliefs. We have a huge library in our databanks. We could offer them the whole thing. All the great literature of dozens of cultures.

In a later scene:

> JANEWAY: I'd be happy to share it with you. Gath, I want you to know I understand your reluctance to share your technology with us. We have similar restrictions. But I wondered, would it make any difference if I gave you my word that we would destroy the trajector matrix as soon as we'd used it?
>
> GATH: I know this will upset you, but I can't.
>
> JANEWAY: I understand. And frankly, I suspected as much. But I have a proposal which might allow you to obey your laws and still give us what we want. Surely you could use the trajectory to send us? Forty thousand light years would mean a great deal to us. And in return, we're prepared to offer you something you might enjoy.
>
> GATH: Oh?
>
> JANEWAY: A full library of the Federation's finest literature.
>
> GATH: Literature?
>
> JANEWAY: Centuries of stories. New stories from diverse cultures. Stories that fire the imagination.
>
> GATH: You certainly know how to tempt me, Captain. It's certainly possible. I'll have to meet with the other Magistrates to discuss it. No one has ever made a request like that. In the meantime, I'd like to enjoy every bite of this, how did you call it?
>
> JANEWAY: Pecan pie.

Comment: thanks! I had remembered it differently where the alien race were pressuring the crew to give them the stories. I was looking for a morale tale about the dangers of too much stories (vis a vis modern day netflix)

Comment: It's possible that you are mixing it up with the [Voyager episode Random Thoughts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Random_Thoughts_%28episode%29), which is about violent thoughts that are forbidden in the culture of a telepathic species.